Customize displayed product tags in WooCommerce single product page
Right now, in WooCommerce single product page, my product tags are displayed like this:
<span class="tagged_as">All tags: <span class="tagged_as">
<a href="" rel="tag">000</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag">100</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag">200</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag">300</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag">400</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag">500</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag">600</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag">700</a>
</span></span>

I need to insert <span>#</span> for each product tag like this:
<span class="tagged_as">All tags: <span class="tagged_as">
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>000</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>100</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>200</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>300</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>400</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>500</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>600</a>, 
<a href="" rel="tag"><span>#</span>700</a>
</span></span>

So I tried to do it with the following:
function custom_product_tag_output( $tag_list ) {
    // Если теги есть, добавляем символ "#" перед каждым тегом
    if ( $tag_list ) {
        // Используем регулярное выражение для добавления символа "#" перед каждым тегом
        $tag_list = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(<a[^>]+>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/',
            function($matches) {
                return $matches[1] . '<span>#</span>' . $matches[2] . $matches[3];
            },
            $tag_list
        );
        // Добавляем обертку div
        $tag_list = '<span class="tagged_as">' . $tag_list . '</span>';
    }

    return $tag_list;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tag_list', 'custom_product_tag_output', 10, 1 );

But it has no effect and doesn't work at all.
How to customize displayed product tags in single product page?

Note that the hook woocommerce_product_tag_list doesn't exist and there is no available filter hook for product tag list in single product page.
But as you can override WooCommerce template files via your theme, copy single-product/meta.php template file inside your theme in a folder named "woocommerce".
Once done, open/edit this file, and replace (line 36):
<?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

with the following:
<?php 
$product_tags = wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );

echo str_replace('rel="tag">', 'rel="tag"><span>#</span>', $product_tags); 
?>

Tested and works.
